# Read A tab's console output from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**I need to develop a simple Chrome Extension for work that inspects
Chrome's JS console for a certain value.**

***Further Explanation:***

Basically, the need for this, is I need to know when a certain JS event has completed. I have placed a console.log("complete!") in my code to inform me when it is done.

> The problem I am facing, **I cannot seem to find a way for a chrome extension to read output from the JS Console.**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't read the console output from JS, not even on a regular webpage. You would have to hijack the `console` methods and save what is passed to them, and then do searches on the saved data.

From your goal it seems like you simply want to trigger a new event. Which you can do by creating a [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)/[CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent), setting up a listener for it, and firing off the event whenever you need it to be triggered.

```
document.addEventListener("eventdone",function(e){
   console.log("The events done, now do work here");
});
//then whereever you had console.log("complete!")
var event = new CustomEvent('eventdone', { 'detail': 'Extra data' });
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**Demo**

```js
document.addEventListener("eventdone",function(e){
  document.body.innerHTML = "Event done";
});

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(e){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var event = new CustomEvent('eventdone', { 'detail': 'Extra data' });
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
  },2000);
});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```